# 2sxc - dnn - News app v3.1.5 - Problem with filtering

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Hello 2sxc News app experts,

hopefully you can help me with my 2sxc News app v3.1.5 (2sxc v10.25.2).

I am struggeling with following problem: On one page I inserted the News app. Created some categories (category1..3). After this I created some news items and chose one category for every news item.

After this I created a News module on another tab to show the newest 3 items of a dedicated category. I modified the ViewConfiguration (id of the previous module, tab of the previous module, "category1").

What I expected was to see all news items of "category1". But unfortunately I see all items. The filter did not work.

What I tried so far (with no success):

- Recreation of categories (delete categories from news items, deletion of all Categories, creation of categories, adding one category to a news item).
- Export and reimport of data (export all data to xml, deletion of all data, reimport of all data)

What I can see in query designer is, that the link from "ModuleDataSource" to "View Category" is showing 1 item (probably the category of the ViewConfiguration), but the result of RelationshipFilter after "View Category" to "StreamFallback" is showing 0 items. So the fallback comes in play and all items are showing.

From here I have no idea what to check or what to configure, to get the Category of the ViewConfiguration get working. Has anyone a hint or an idea?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow :)

So first of all - we just released a new News app V4 today! https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/news-app-v4

It's a complete rework of the News so if you're just getting started - I would start there. My guess is whatever you need is already fixed ;)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for this news. Unfortunately 1 day too late... Is there a migration path to get the data migrated from 3.1.5 to 4?
BTW: the above described problem we came around by replacing blanks with underscores in the category names.

Comment: I'll see if we can add a checklist for that. It's basically export/import data...